# What is a channel up key (in javafx)?

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard

I was looking at the documentation for JavaFX.scene.input.KeyCode on Oracle and I noticed there were `CHANNEL_UP` and  `KP_UP methods`. `KP_UP` is obviously the up on the keyboard, but I'm confused as to what would be the `CHANNEL_UP` button.

Comment: I am guessing it's to cover keyboards that have `TV` controls.